# Go: Anonymous Func Only Taking Last Value in For Range

Tags: loops, go, race-condition, anonymous-function, goroutine

I imagine this is a pretty easy fix. Just trying loop through the string list `urls` and print out each `url` as the loop iterates. But when I add in concurrency (with `go` and `WaitGroup`) all it prints out is the last `url` in the list.

**Why is it only printing out the last `url` (when printed from the anon function) rather than each `url` individually as the loop iterates?**

Go Playground: http://play.golang.org/p/z4IZLY7Mt_

---

Code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

var urls = []string{
    "http://google.com",
    "http://facebook.com",
    "http://youtube.com",
    "http://yahoo.com",
    "http://baidu.com",
    "http://wikipedia.org",
    "http://twitter.com",
    "http://live.com",
    "http://amazon.com",
    "http://linkedin.com",
    "http://google.co.in",
}

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for _, url := range urls {
        fmt.Println("correct: " + url)
        wg.Add(1)
        go func() {
            fmt.Println("wrong: " + url)
            wg.Done()
        }()
    }

    wg.Wait()
}
```

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/go-wiki/wiki/CommonMistakes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

var urls = []string{
    "http://google.com",
    "http://facebook.com",
    "http://youtube.com",
    "http://yahoo.com",
    "http://baidu.com",
    "http://wikipedia.org",
    "http://twitter.com",
    "http://live.com",
    "http://amazon.com",
    "http://linkedin.com",
    "http://google.co.in",
}

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for _, url := range urls {
        fmt.Println("correct: " + url)
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(url string) {
            fmt.Println("wrong: " + url)
            wg.Done()
        }(url)
    }

    wg.Wait()
}
```

Also on go playground: http://play.golang.org/p/zFSDvfdIDS

Comment: Although correct, this isn't a useful answer in the sense accepted on stackoverflow, as it's just a link to an external site. The format here is that questions and answers should be more-or-less self-contained.

Answer (score 0):

Adding my answer because the accepted one does not explain WHY.

A closure in Go has access to all the variables of the scope where it's created. So every closure being created in the example below has access to the loop variable `url`.

```golang
func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for _, url := range urls {
        fmt.Println("correct: " + url)
        wg.Add(1)
        go func() {
            fmt.Println("wrong: " + url)
            wg.Done()
        }()
    }

    wg.Wait()
}
```

Therefore, when every closure starts running concunrrently, value of `url` can be any element of `urls` slice(in most cases the last element, but not every time), because it's not blocking the `main` go routine. To make use of proper values for each closures, we need to copy the proper value to use. For example, you can do this:

```golang
func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for _, url := range urls {
        fmt.Println("correct: " + url)
        url2 = url
        wg.Add(1)
        go func() {
            fmt.Println("wrong: " + url2)
            wg.Done()
        }()
    }

    wg.Wait()
}
```

Or can do what's already in the previous answer, which is more explicit and readable:

```golang
func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for _, url := range urls {
        fmt.Println("correct: " + url)
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(url string) {
            fmt.Println("wrong: " + url)
            wg.Done()
        }(url)
    }

    wg.Wait()
}
```

Comment: This behavior is being changed from Go 1.22. We don't have to copy the loop variable anymore.